# Hangman - can't use words with letters repeating more than 3 times

Tags: javascript, arrays, svg, dom, duplicates

I am creating a hangman game using SVG, and everything is functioning perfectly. However, whenever a word contains more than 3 of the same letter, the word is unable to be used correctly. I've used multiple different ways of finding the duplicates and nothing seems to fix the problem.
For the sake of investigating the problem, I changed the random number to always equal 1, where basketball has 4 ls, thus letting me identify the problem. However, I am still struggling to find the source of the issue.

```js
let wordArr = [];
let dupeArr = [];
let dupeArr1 = [];
let dupeArr2 = [];
let dupeArr3 = [];
let dupeArr4 = [];
let dupeArr5 = [];
let dupeArr6 = [];
let dupeArr7 = [];
let arrOfDupes = [dupeArr, dupeArr1, dupeArr2, dupeArr3]
let hangmanNum = 0;
let yes = document.getElementsByClassName("yes");
newArr = [];
let endSet = []
let startEr = []


function gameStart() {
  let playAgainSet = document.querySelectorAll(".playAgain")
  playAgainSet.forEach(e => {
    endSet.push(e)
  })
  endSet.forEach(e => {
    e.setAttribute("display", "none")
  })
  console.log(endSet)
  let startSet = document.querySelectorAll(".start")
  startSet.forEach(e => {
    startEr.push(e)
  })
  startEr.forEach(e => {
    e.setAttribute("display", "none")
  })
  console.log(startEr)
  let lost = document.getElementById("youLost")
  lost.setAttribute("display", "none")

  let alphabet = document.querySelectorAll(".alphabet")
  let alphArr = []
  alphabet.forEach(e => {
    alphArr.push(e)
  })
  alphArr.forEach(e => {
    e.setAttribute("fill", "black")
  })
  var wordsToChooseFrom = ["b ,a ,s ,k ,e ,t ,b ,a ,l ,l ,l ,l ", "s ,o ,c ,c ,e ,r ", "l ,a ,c ,r ,o ,s ,s ,e ", "f ,o ,o ,t ,b ,a ,l ,l ", "h ,o ,c ,k ,e ,y ", "g ,o ,l ,f ", "g ,y ,m ,n ,a ,s ,t ,i ,c ,s ", "t ,e ,n ,n ,i ,s ", "b ,a ,d ,m ,i ,n ,t ,o ,n ", "v ,o ,l ,l ,e ,y ,b ,a ,l ,l ", "s ,w ,i ,m ,m ,i ,n ,g ", "w ,r ,e ,s ,t ,l ,i ,n ,g ", "f ,i ,e ,l ,d , ,h ,o ,c ,k ,e ,y ", "l ,l ,l ,l "]

  function getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max)
  }
  var wordBox = document.getElementById('randomWord')
  //        var randomI = getRandomInt(10)
  var randomI = 0;
  let word = wordsToChooseFrom[randomI]

  wordArr = word.split(",") //.join(" ")
  //  wordArr.replace(",", " ")
  /*  wordArr.forEach(letter => {
        
    })*/
  console.log(wordArr)



  //wordArr = ["b ","a ","s ","k ","e ", "t ", "b ", "a ", "l ", "l "]
  // wordBox.textContent = []
  wordBox.setAttribute("display", "block")
  let x = 250;
  let y = 200;
  const svg = document.querySelector('svg')
  let underline = document.getElementById("randomWordUnderline")
  underline.textContent = ""
  for (let i = 0; i < wordArr.length; i++) {
    underline.textContent += "_ "
  }
  console.log(underline.textContent)
  let letteri = 0;
  let index = 0;
  var length = wordArr.length;

  function findDupes(arry) {
    for (let i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++) {
      for (let j = i + 1; j <= length; j++) {
        if (arr[i] === arr[j]) {
          newArr[index] = arr[i]
          index++
          console.log(index)
        }
      }
    }
    return newArr;


    /*let toFindDuplicates = arry => arry.filter((item, index) => arry.indexOf(item) !== index)
                newArr = toFindDuplicates(arry);
                console.log(newArr);
                }
           console.log(findDupes(wordArr))
           console.log(newArr)*/
    // let DupeArr = [];
    /*  for (i=0; i<newArr.length; i++) {
       DupeArr[i] = [];
       console.log(DupeArr);
      }*/
    let newArri = 0;
    newArr.forEach(letter => {
      /*for (i=0; i<wordArr.length; i++) {
          if (wordArr[i]== letter) {
              console.log(wordArr.indexOf(letter))
          }
      }*/
      let idx = wordArr.indexOf(letter)
      console.log(idx)
      while (idx !== -1) {

        arrOfDupes[newArri].push(idx)
        idx = wordArr.indexOf(letter, idx + 1)
      }

      console.log(arrOfDupes[newArri])
      newArri += 1
    })
  }
  wordArr.forEach(letter => {
    let letterNum = wordArr.indexOf(letter)
    // console.log(letterNum)
    //  let letNumString = letterNum.toString()
    let numBox = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text")
    numBox.setAttribute("x", x)
    numBox.setAttribute("y", y)
    numBox.setAttribute("display", "block")
    numBox.setAttribute("stroke", "transparent")
    numBox.setAttribute("fill", "transparent")
    numBox.setAttribute("class", "letter")
    numBox.textContent = letter
    if (newArr.includes(letter)) {
      numBox.setAttribute("id", letter + letteri)

      console.log(letteri)
      console.log("yes")
    } else {
      numBox.setAttribute("id", letter)
      //      console.log("no")
    }
    numBox.setAttribute("font-size", "28")
    numBox.setAttribute("font-family", "monospace")

    svg.appendChild(numBox)
    x += 35;
    letteri += 1;
    //   console.log(numBox.getAttribute("id"))


  })






}

function letterClicked() {
  var thisLetter = event.srcElement.id
  event.srcElement.setAttribute("fill", "transparent")

  console.log(thisLetter)
  console.log(wordArr)
  if (wordArr.includes(thisLetter + " ")) {
    console.log("yes")
    if (newArr.includes(thisLetter + " ")) {
      /*let idx = wordArr.indexOf(thisLetter) 
                let idxArr = []
                while (idx !== -1) {
                    idxArr.push(idx)
                    idx = wordArr.indexOf(thisLetter, idx + 1)
               }*/
      let findArr = wordArr.indexOf(thisLetter + " ")
      console.log(findArr)
      let tempArr;
      arrOfDupes.forEach(array => {
        if (array.includes(findArr))

          tempArr = array
        console.log(tempArr)
      })
      // let numOfLetters = 0
      let arrOfLetter = []
      tempArr.forEach(num => {
        console.log(num)
        let letterNum = wordArr[num]
        arrOfLetter.push(letterNum + num)
        console.log(arrOfLetter)
        console.log(wordArr)
      })
      arrOfLetter.forEach(letter => {
        let letterShow = document.getElementById(letter)

        letterShow.setAttribute("stroke", "black")
        letterShow.setAttribute("fill", "black")
        letterShow.setAttribute("class", "yes")
        console.log(letterShow)
        let newArri = 0;
        let arrofWords = []
      })



      /*for (i=0; i<wordArr.length; i++) {
          if (wordArr[i]== letter) {
              console.log(wordArr.indexOf(letter))
          }
      }*/
      /*  let idx = wordArr.indexOf(letter) 

        while (idx !== -1) {
            arrofWords.push(idx)
            idx = wordArr.indexOf(letter, idx + 1)
       }
       
        console.log(arrofWords)
        newArri += 1*/



    } else {
      let letterShow = document.getElementById(thisLetter + " ")
      letterShow.setAttribute("stroke", "black")
      letterShow.setAttribute("fill", "black")
      console.log(letterShow)
      letterShow.setAttribute("class", "yes")
    }

  } else {
    console.log("hangman")
    let hangmanEl = document.getElementById("hangman" + hangmanNum)
    hangmanEl.setAttribute("stroke", "black")
    hangmanNum += 1;
  }

  if (wordArr.length == yes.length) {
    console.log("won")
    endSet.forEach(e => {
      e.setAttribute("display", "block")
    })
    let yesArr = []
    console.log(yes)
    let allLetters = document.querySelectorAll(".yes")
    allLetters.forEach(e => {
      yesArr.push(e)
    })

    yesArr.forEach(e => {
      e.setAttribute("display", "none")
    })
  } else if (hangmanNum == 5) {
    console.log("lost")
    endSet.forEach(e => {
      e.setAttribute("display", "block")
    })
    let win = document.getElementById("youWin")
    win.setAttribute("display", "none")
    console.log(win.getAttribute)
    let lost = document.getElementById("youLost")
    lost.setAttribute("display", "block")
    let yesArr = []
    console.log(yes)
    let allLetters = document.querySelectorAll(".yes")
    allLetters.forEach(e => {
      yesArr.push(e)
    })

    yesArr.forEach(e => {
      e.setAttribute("display", "none")
    })
  }

  /*  wordArr.forEach(letter => {
       if(letter == thisLetter + " ") {
        
       }
    })*/


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Hangman</title>
  <script lang="javascript">
  </script>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0;">
  <h1>Hangman</h1>
  <svg width="700" height="600" style="background-color: purple;">
        <rect x="10" y="300" height="30" width="150" fill="gray"></rect>
        <rect x="10" y="270" height="30" width="125" fill="gray"></rect>
        <rect x="10" y="240" height="30" width="100" fill="gray"></rect>
        <line x1="50" y1="240" x2="50" y2="50" stroke="gray" stroke-width="5px"></line>
        <line x1="47" y1="50" x2="150" y2="50" stroke="gray" stroke-width="5px"></line>   
        <line x1="150" y1="47" x2="150" y2="80" stroke="gray" stroke-width="5px"></line> 
        <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="20" fill="none" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" id="hangman0"></circle>
        <line x1="150" y1="120" x2="150" y2="200" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" id="hangman1"></line>
        <line x1="150" y1="140" x2="120" y2="120" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" id="hangman2"></line>
        <line x1="150" y1="140" x2="180" y2="120" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" id="hangman3"></line>
        <line x1="150" y1="197" x2="120" y2="220" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" id="hangman4"></line>
        <line x1="150" y1="197" x2="180" y2="220" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" id="hangman5"></line>
        <text x="50" y="450" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="a" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">A</text>
        <text x="90" y="450" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="b" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">B</text>
        <text x="130" y="450" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="c" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">C</text>
        <text x="170" y="450" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="d" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">D</text>
        <text x="210" y="450" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="e" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">E</text>
        <text x="250" y="450" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="f" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">F</text>
        <text x="290" y="450" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="g" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">G</text>
        <text x="330" y="450" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="h" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">H</text>
        <text x="370" y="450" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="i" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">I</text>
        <text x="410" y="450" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="j" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">J</text>
        <text x="450" y="450" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="k" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">K</text>
        <text x="490" y="450" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="l" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">L</text>
        <text x="530" y="450" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="m" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">M</text>
        <text x="50" y="500" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="n" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">N</text>
        <text x="90" y="500" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="o" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">O</text>
        <text x="130" y="500" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="p" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">P</text>
        <text x="170" y="500" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="q" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">Q</text>
        <text x="210" y="500" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="r" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">R</text>
        <text x="250" y="500" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="s" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">S</text>
        <text x="290" y="500" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="t" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">T</text>
        <text x="330" y="500" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="u" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">U</text>
        <text x="370" y="500" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="v" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">V</text>
        <text x="410" y="500" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="w" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">W</text>
        <text x="450" y="500" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="x" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">X</text>
        <text x="490" y="500" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="y" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">Y</text>
        <text x="530" y="500" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="z" onclick="letterClicked()" class="alphabet">Z</text>
        <text x="250" y="200" font-size="40" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="randomWordUnderline" >_________</text>

        <text x="250" y="200" font-size="28" font-weight="bold" font-family="monospace" id="randomWord" letter-spacing="0" id="0"></text>
             <!--  <text x="285" y="200" font-size="28" font-weight="bold" font-family="monospace" id="randomWord" letter-spacing="0" id="1"></text>
        <text x="320" y="200" font-size="28" font-weight="bold" font-family="monospace" id="randomWord" letter-spacing="0" id="2">h</text>
        <text x="355" y="200" font-size="28" font-weight="bold" font-family="monospace" id="randomWord" letter-spacing="0" id="3">h</text>
        <text x="385" y="200" font-size="28" font-weight="bold" font-family="monospace" id="randomWord" letter-spacing="0" id="4">h</text>
        <text x="420" y="200" font-size="28" font-weight="bold" font-family="monospace" id="randomWord" letter-spacing="0" id="5">h</text>
        <text x="455" y="200" font-size="28" font-weight="bold" font-family="monospace" id="randomWord" letter-spacing="0" id="6">h</text>
        <text x="490" y="200" font-size="28" font-weight="bold" font-family="monospace" id="randomWord" letter-spacing="0" id="7">h</text>
        <text x="520" y="200" font-size="28" font-weight="bold" font-family="monospace" id="randomWord" letter-spacing="0" id="8">h</text>
        <text x="555" y="200" font-size="28" font-weight="bold" font-family="monospace" id="randomWord" letter-spacing="0" id="9">h</text>
-->
    <rect x="100" y="100" width="400" height="400" fill="white" class="playAgain"></rect>
    <rect x="200" y="290" height="100" width="200"fill="pink" rx="10"class="playAgain"></rect>
    <text x="200" y="250" font-size="50" class="playAgain" display="none" id="youWin">You win!</text>
    <text x="200" y="250" font-size="50" id="youLost" display="none">You lost...</text>

    <text x="225" y="350" font-size="30" onclick="gameStart()" class="playAgain" display="none"> Play Again?</text>
    
    <text x="200" y="250" font-size="50" class="start">Hangman!</text>
    <text x="275" y="350" font-size="30" onclick="gameStart()" class="start"> Play</text>

</svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In `findDupes()`, none of the code after `return newArr` will execute, since `return` ends the function execution.

Comment: `j <= length` should be `j < length` since the last valid index is `length-1`.

Comment: Why does `wordsToChooseFrom` contain comma-separated strings instead of nested arrays? You're just going to split it into an array, so why not just store them as arrays in the first place? The spaces before all the commas are likely to cause problems, too.

Comment: Could you narrow the code snippet down to just the part that's giving you trouble? This is way too much code, especially with all the commented-out and unreachable code.

Comment: Why do you even need to "find duplicates" as a special action? When the user guesses a letter, just go through the word and find all the places of that letter.